# Export grades to a spreadsheet in Google classroom with script automation

Tags: google-classroom

Is there any way to export grades (not csv) to a spreadsheet with a script in order to manage the data and create automatic processes like emails and statistics?

Thank you so much

Comment: How are your grades stored?

Comment: I suppose that the grades are stored in the assessments in Google Classroom. There is an option to export them to csv. But I'd like to connect the grades with a spreadsheet with automatic refresh. It will be work like a form more or less or like a import range in order to work with my digital gradebook.  Is this possible? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this time the Google Classroom API doesn't provide access to grade data.